# Install the same Active Directory Schema extension again

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, installation, lync, schema

is there any possibilty of problems, due to a 2nd time installation of the schema extension for a lync server, in an active directory childdomain of a forest?
Replication overhead would not be that relevant...

Have searched, but not found any evidence of duing this a second time...

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AD schema is basically a list of all the types of objects that can exist in an AD instance, as well as the properties such objects can have. It's basically a blueprint. Installing a schema extension/update merely adds object types and properties to the list, so running such an update multiple times isn't really much of a hassle.

The worst that can happen is that the update process detects that the changes it wanted to make have already been made, and it may not run for that reason.